# Angular 15.1 mat-tab-nav-bar require TabPanel

Tags: angular, angular-material

I recently upgraded my project to Angular 15.1 and noticed a new problem.

On a page I have a mat-tab-nav which opene subpages via routing:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar color="primary">
  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [routerLink]="link.link" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">{{link.label}}< /a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

After the update everything works fine but in the console I see the error "**A mat-tab-nav-panel must be specified via [tabPanel].**"

Looking at the Angular code (line 385) https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/tabs/tab-nav-bar/tab-nav-bar.ts
I see the code:

```
override ngAfterViewInit() {
 if (!this.tabPanel && (typeof ngDevMode === 'undefined' || ngDevMode)) {
   throw new Error('A mat-tab-nav-panel must be specified via [tabPanel].');
 }
 super.ngAfterViewInit();
}
```

From the documentation (https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api
tabPanel) it looks like the tabPanel may be null:

> tabPanel: associated tab panel controlled by the nav bar. If not provided, then the nav bar follows the ARIA link / navigation landmark pattern. If provided, it follows the ARIA tabs design pattern.

I fixed it by adding a useless mat-tab-nav-panel to my code:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar color="primary" [tabPanel]="tabPanel">
  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [routerLink]="link.link" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">{{link.label}}< /a>
</nav>
<mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel></mat-tab-nav-panel>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Is this the correct way?
It seems to me a bug of the Angular component. What do you think?

Comment: For accessibility reason Yes you should provide empty mat-tab-nav-panel

Comment: Hey I have the same issue thanks for your post. However I have another issue. the tab-nav-bar does not have Ink-bar not even in the dom. do you have that problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In my Opinion you have to wrap the Router Outlet in an `<mat-tab-nav-panel>`:

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar color="primary" [tabPanel]="tabPanel">
  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navLinks" [routerLink]="link.link" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">{{link.label}}< /a>
</nav>
<mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-tab-nav-panel>
```

The Documentaton states
*"The corresponding `<router-outlet>` must be wrapped in an `<mat-tab-nav-panel>` component and should typically be placed relatively close to the mat-tab-nav-bar (see Accessibility)."*
see [Angular Material Tabs: Tabs and navigation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation)
Although the code example from Angular Team is currently missing the Router-Outlet.

Answer (score 5):

In newer versions (I needed it for Angular 16) you must make sure to add `[tabPanel]="tabPanel"` to the **`<nav mat-tab-nav-bar></nav>`** containing the tab links:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a
        mat-tab-link
        [routerLink]="['/some/link']"
        [active]="isActiveTab('active_tab_name')"
        (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged('active_tab_name')"
    >
        My Tab Title
    </a>
</nav>

<mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-tab-nav-panel>
```

to

```
<nav
    mat-tab-nav-bar
    [tabPanel]="tabPanel" // <---- add this one here
>
    <a
        mat-tab-link
        [routerLink]="['/some/link']"
        [active]="isActiveTab('active_tab_name')"
        (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged('active_tab_name')"
    >
        My Tab Title
    </a>
</nav>
<mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-tab-nav-panel>
```